# Shortcut to hiding everything in the view except the Progressbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I have several *Views* in my layout. During background loading, I wish to set the Visibility of my ProgressBar to `View.VISIBLE` and everything else to `View.INVISIBLE`. Needless to say, after loading I wish to do the reverse.
I wish to know if anyone has figured out a smart way to do this. I tried this

```
constraintLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

But unfortunately, that did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: I think this is perfect except use gone instead of invisible.. and you can also hide all the views programatically by using for loop in viewgroup which makes all view to gone visibility..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Progressbar Should be visibility "gone" by default, visible it once process started and set other view elements visibility "gone". And then do it vice versa when process completes.